# Origen del infijo "-uc-" en "besucón"

Tags: etimología, sufijos

Viendo dibujos con los niños, en un episodio de [Blaze](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaze_and_the_Monster_Machines) (esa serie que anima a los niños a ser ingenieros) apareció un oso que se dedicaba a comerse a besos a sus presas, y uno de los personajes lo llamó el "oso besador". Más adelante, en otro episodio usaron la expresión que yo habría empleado en la traducción: "oso besucón".

Me resulta muy curiosa esa mutación de la *-o* final de *beso*, transformándose en el infijo *-uc-* antes de formar el aumentativo. La única otra palabra que he visto que sufre un cambio similar es *bravucón*, de *bravo*.

Ahora viene lo curioso. Uno podría pensar que en realidad ese infijo *-uc-* proviene de los verbos *besuquear* y *bravuconear*, que sí lo llevan. Pero resulta que no es así, sino al revés. Según el DLE, *[bravuconear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=648f3eh)* se formó a partir de *[bravucón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=640Cfuc)*, y este de *[bravo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=63pF2Fd)*, luego el infijo *-uc-* se creó al formar el aumentativo. En el caso de *[besuquear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5Q1zBY0)*, este viene de *[besucar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5PuDPha)*, pero para este no se indica la etimología.

Así pues, ¿cuál es el origen de ese infijo *-uc-* encontrado en *besucón* y *bravucón*? Y, en caso de que aplique, ¿tienen *[grandullón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JSb1xCn)* y *[grandulón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JSfKTOz)* (de *grande*) un origen similar? Corominas cita el primer uso de *besucar* en 1607, y de *bravucón* en 1836, por lo que el primero pudo haber influido en la creación del segundo. Aunque la palabra puede ser anterior, a juzgar por el CORDE:

> *Ahotas que dos cordones
>
>   me dieron porque hiz sones,
>
>   á una dí dos besucones
>
>   que como la miél sabié.*
>
> Anónimo, "Cancionero de obras de burlas provocantes a risa", c1445-1519 (España).

Comment: La *u* parece muy propensa a formar esos derivados (aumentativos o expresivos): con *-uc-* están *ventanuco* y *mujeruca* (y en Argentina *brasuca* y *peruca* por *brasileño* y *peruano*).

Comment: Estoy con @pablodf76 , no es un infijo sino un sufijo sobre el cual se ha puesto otro sufijo.  *beso* a ***besuco*** a *besucón*.  (*-uco* se usa mucho en el norte de España)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Besucar* igual que *besucón* (como notas) aparece primero en el siglo XVI:

> **Quincia.** Y contigo vayan, señor. ¿Esto quedava por hazer? ¡Ay, Jesús!, ¿no estás ya farto de besucar?
>
> ...
>
> **Quincia.** Acabemos ya de besucar, que es desonrra, auiéndonos visto el señor Rodancho como estáuamos y tan brcue ser como insensatos.
>
> - *Segunda/Tercera Celestina* (1534, 1536)

> La boca, hermoso paseo
>   de apetito que besuca,
>   cuando, por sobra de lenguas,
>   acontece que esté muda.
>
> - *Poesías*, Quevedo y Villegas (1597 - 1645)

Pero también hay *besuco*:

> ¿Cómo andan los abrazos y besucos;
>   son menester dos huevos de cabritos?
>
> - *Poseías*, Francisco de Aldana (c 1560 - a 1578)

Así que, creo que la evolución era algo así:

- beso

  - besuco<sup>1</sup> <sup>(+ [-uco](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b0o6oUH))</sup>

    - besucón <sup>(+ ón)</sup>
    - besucar <sup>(+ -ar)</sup>
    - besuquear <sup>(+ -ear)</sup>

Hay unas más palabras así. Dos pájaros:

- diuca > diucón
- alūcus > alucón

Y un par de palabras más simlares:

- peluca > pelucona
- machucar > machucón
- bravar > bravucón

Todos estos ejemplos tienen una *-uc-* etimológica, salvo que *bravucón* (que también has notado), que podemos asumir se ha pasado el mismo tipo de evolución.

---

> <sup>1. **Besuco,** m. ant. Bejuco. || Beso dado de mala gana, con mal arte.</sup>
>   <sup>- 1918 RODRÍGUEZ NAVAS</sup>